# Можете подсказать, что нужно исправить в методе чтобы он сбрасывал значение на 0 в конкретном столбце из базы данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, discord

Вообщем этот метод проверяет значение в конкретном столбце из таблицы базы данных, вообщем мне нужно, чтобы этот метод проверял значение в конкретном столбце и сбрасывал в нем значение на 0. библиотека discord.net бд entity framework core, желательно дайте ответ кодом пожалуйста.

```
public static int ResetUserXp(ulong UserId, ulong GuildId)
        {
            using var DbContext = new SqlDbContext();
            IQueryable<Level> ds = DbContext.Levels;
            return ds.Where(x => x.UserId == UserId && x.GuildId == GuildId).Select(x => x.XP).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: Вы что то самостоятельно пытались сделать? Есть какие то наработки? Покажите, как вы пробовали решить свою проблему?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну пробовал в конце добавить return ds == null; пишет что нельзя преобразовать int в bool

Comment: ну это вам никак не поможет. Вам наверное лучше 1) получить нужный вам Level 2) Поменять в нем что хотите 3) Созранить изменения `DbContext.SaveChanges()` или типа того

Comment: Почему метод называется Reset**User**Xp? А внутри, судя по названию, используется Level, а не User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш метод должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
public static void ResetUserXp(ulong userId, ulong guildId)
{
    using var dbContext = new SqlDbContext();
    var levels = dbContext.Levels;
    var level = levels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId && x.GuildId == guildId);
    level.XP = 0;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Находим нужную сущность. Я обозначил её `level`, так как таблица зовётся `Levels`.
Меняем у сущности какое-либо значение - `XP`.
Сохраняем изменения вызовом `SaveChanges()`.

Метод ничего не возвращает, т. к. нечего возвращать, судя по смыслу и названию.

Исправил имена параметров и переменных в соответствии с принятыми правилами.

---

Асинхронная версия:

```
public static async Task ResetUserXpAsync(ulong userId, ulong guildId)
{
    using var dbContext = new SqlDbContext();
    var levels = dbContext.Levels;
    var level = await levels.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId == userId && x.GuildId == guildId);
    level.XP = 0;
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: из-за моего не точного описания моей проблемы, вы не правильно построили ответ, зарнее дико извиняюсь, всё дело в том, что мне этот метод нужно будет вызвать в другом классе через await а я это не могу сделать из-за void.

Comment: @magicrain - обновил ответ

Comment: Очень сильно вас благодарю, спасибо вам огромное всё работает! Вы вернули мою надежду к Ru stackowerflow коммьюнити. Ещё раз спасибо!